# Getting an error when creating Superuser in Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, superuser

File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 179, in 
for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
TypeError: create_profile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'senerd'

Getting this error when creating a Superuser in Django with VS Code terminal, did I miss something? anyone else get this before?

Answer (score 0):

Please add more detailed code so I could try to help better, did you created an user model? In any case, try the following -

1. Use the `--username` flag instead of directly passing a username:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --username yourusername
```

2. Make sure you imported the model correctly in the admin.py file.
3. Check that this row appears in the INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
```

4. Try migrating the changes and then run createsuperuser.

I hope one of them solves the problem.